# ORA-02253 sqlplus constraint error question

Tags: oracle

```
SQL> create table emp(
  2  empno      number(4)
  3  constraint pk_emp primary key,
  4  ename varchar2(10),
  5  job varchar2(9),
  6  mgr        number(4)
  7     constraint fk_mgr reference emp(empno),
  8  hiredate date,
  9  sal        number(7,2),
 10  comm       number(7,2),
 11  deptno     number(2)
 12     constraint fk_deptno reference emp(empno));
        constraint fk_mgr reference emp(empno),
        *

ORA-02253
```

I wrote it exactly as I saw it in the book, but I don't know why this error occurs. I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is "reference**s**", not "reference".

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE emp
  2  (
  3     empno      NUMBER (4) CONSTRAINT pk_emp PRIMARY KEY,
  4     ename      VARCHAR2 (10),
  5     job        VARCHAR2 (9),
  6     mgr        NUMBER (4) CONSTRAINT fk_mgr REFERENCES emp (empno),
  7     hiredate   DATE,
  8     sal        NUMBER (7, 2),
  9     comm       NUMBER (7, 2),
 10     deptno     NUMBER (2) CONSTRAINT fk_deptno REFERENCES emp (empno)
 11  );

Table created.

SQL>
```